# NullPointerException when moving from activity to another

Tags: android, android-intent, nullpointerexception, android-activity

Im developing a game in android where u finish four-question test and get back to main menu,
now going to main menu activity to test activity is fine no problems, but whenever im in test activity and tried to get back to main menu by finishing 4 questions or onPressedBack() function or by pressing main menu button on dialog it will give me NullPointerException.
here is my test code:

```
 public class Test extends Activity implements OnClickListener{

TextView tvBorder, tvBorder2, tvOperation, tvRight, tvWrong, tvTotal, tvTimer;
Button bMcq1, bMcq2, bMcq3, bMcq4;
ImageButton ibMusic, ibPause;
Timer t;
MediaPlayer mp;

private String name;
private int difficulty;
private int ops[];
private int TotalCounter = 0;
private int TimeCounter = 0;
private int right = 0, wrong = 0;
private double answer = -1;
private boolean ispressed = false;

private Plus plus;
private Minus minus;
private Multi multi;
private Division div;
private RandomizedQueue<Integer> rd;

Random rand = new Random();



@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.test);

    difficulty = getIntent().getExtras().getInt("Difficulty");
    Log.d("test Difficulty 2", String.valueOf(difficulty));
    ops = getIntent().getExtras().getIntArray("OPstring");
    Log.d("OPS 2", String.valueOf(ops.length));
    name = getIntent().getExtras().getString("Reference2");
    Log.d("Reference2", name);




    Initialize();

    generateQuestions();



}

private void Initialize() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.game);
    mp.setLooping(true);
    mp.start();

    tvBorder = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.border);
    tvBorder2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.border2);
    tvOperation = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.op);
    tvRight = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.right);
    tvWrong = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.wrong);
    tvTotal = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.total);
    tvTimer = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.timer);

    bMcq1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.mcq1);
    bMcq2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.mcq2);
    bMcq3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.mcq3);
    bMcq4 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.mcq4);

    ibMusic = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.music);
    ibPause = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.pausemenu);

    t = new Timer();
    t.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    tvTimer.setText(String.valueOf(TimeCounter));
                    TimeCounter++;
                }
            });

        }
    }, 1000, 1000);

    bMcq1.setOnClickListener(this);
    bMcq2.setOnClickListener(this);
    bMcq3.setOnClickListener(this);
    bMcq4.setOnClickListener(this);
    ibMusic.setOnClickListener(this);
    ibPause.setOnClickListener(this);
}



private void generateQuestions() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    if(TotalCounter == 4)
    {
        Intent back = new Intent(Test.this, MainMenu.class);
        startActivity(back);
    }

    plus = new Plus(difficulty);
    minus = new Minus(difficulty);
    multi = new Multi(difficulty);
    div = new Division(difficulty);
    rd = new RandomizedQueue<Integer>();
    TotalCounter++;
    tvTotal.setText(String.valueOf(TotalCounter));

    int gen = rand.nextInt(ops.length);
    Log.d("generated number", String.valueOf(gen));
    int TheChosenOP = ops[gen];
    Log.d("TheChosenOP", String.valueOf(TheChosenOP));

    switch(TheChosenOP)
    {
    case 1:
        Toast t = Toast.makeText(Test.this, "Plus", 5000);
        t.show();
        tvOperation.setText("+");
        int i = plus.getBorder();
        int j = plus.getBorder2();
        tvBorder.setText(String.valueOf(i));
        tvBorder2.setText(String.valueOf(j));
        answer = plus.getAnswer();
        SetAnswer(answer);
        break;

    case 2:
        Toast t2 = Toast.makeText(Test.this, "Minus", 5000);
        t2.show();
        tvOperation.setText("-");
        int i2 = minus.getBorder();
        int j2 = minus.getBorder2();
        tvBorder.setText(String.valueOf(i2));
        tvBorder2.setText(String.valueOf(j2));
        answer = minus.getAnswer();
        SetAnswer(answer);
        break;

    case 3:
        Toast t3 = Toast.makeText(Test.this, "Multi", 5000);
        t3.show();
        tvOperation.setText("*");
        int i3 = multi.getBorder();
        int j3 = multi.getBorder2();
        tvBorder.setText(String.valueOf(i3));
        tvBorder2.setText(String.valueOf(j3));
        answer = multi.getAnswer();
        SetAnswer(answer);
        break;

    case 4:
        Toast t4 = Toast.makeText(Test.this, "Division", 5000);
        t4.show();
        tvOperation.setText("/");
        int i4 = div.getBorder();
        int j4 = div.getBorder2();
        tvBorder.setText(String.valueOf(i4));
        tvBorder2.setText(String.valueOf(j4));
        answer = div.getAnswer();
        SetAnswer(answer);
        break;
}

}

private void SetAnswer(double answer) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    int firstchoice = (int) ((int) answer - ((answer * 10) / 100));
    Log.d("Test", String.valueOf(firstchoice));
    int secondchoice = (int) ((int) answer + Math.ceil(((answer * 10) / 100)));
    int Thirdchoice;
    if (difficulty == 1)
        Thirdchoice = (int) answer + 2;
    else
        Thirdchoice = (int) ((int) answer + Math.ceil(((answer * 25) / 100)));
    rd.enqueue((int) answer);
    rd.enqueue(firstchoice);
    rd.enqueue(secondchoice);
    rd.enqueue(Thirdchoice);

    bMcq1.setText(String.valueOf(rd.dequeue()));
    bMcq2.setText(String.valueOf(rd.dequeue()));
    bMcq3.setText(String.valueOf(rd.dequeue()));
    bMcq4.setText(String.valueOf(rd.dequeue()));
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    String ans;
    switch(v.getId())
    {
    // setting Music
    case R.id.music:
        if (ispressed == false)
        {
            mp.pause();
            ispressed = true;
        }
        else
        {
            mp.start();
            ispressed = false;
        }
        break;

    // setting Pause Menu
    case R.id.pausemenu:
        final Dialog d = new Dialog(this);
        d.setTitle("Pause Menu");
        d.setContentView(R.layout.pausemenu);
        Button resume = (Button) d.findViewById(R.id.Resume);
        Button Back = (Button) d.findViewById(R.id.Main);
        resume.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                d.cancel();
                mp.start();
            }
        });

        Back.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Intent iback = new Intent();
                                    iback.setClass(Test.this, MainMenu.class);
                startActivity(iback);
            }
        });
        mp.pause();
        d.show();
        break;

    //setting answers:
    case R.id.mcq1:
        ans = (String) bMcq1.getText();
        CheckAnswer(ans);
        break;
    case R.id.mcq2:
        ans = (String) bMcq2.getText();
        CheckAnswer(ans);
        break;
    case R.id.mcq3:
        ans = (String) bMcq3.getText();
        CheckAnswer(ans);
        break;
    case R.id.mcq4:
        ans = (String) bMcq4.getText();
        CheckAnswer(ans);
        break;


    }

}

private void CheckAnswer(String ans) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    if (Integer.parseInt(ans) == answer) {
        Toast t = Toast.makeText(this, "True, Bravo!!!", 5000);
        t.show();
        //counter++;
        right++;
        tvRight.setText(String.valueOf(right));
        generateQuestions();
    } else {
        Toast t = Toast.makeText(this,
                "False, Go home u r drunk!!", 5000);
        t.show();

        wrong++;
        tvWrong.setText(String.valueOf(wrong));
        generateQuestions();
    }

}



@Override
protected void onPause() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onPause();
    finish();
}

protected void onStop() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onStop();
    //mp.stop();
}

public void onBackPressed() {
     //TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onBackPressed();
    startActivity(new Intent(this, MainMenu.class));
}


 }
```

on MainMenu activity - this is what matters:

```
 public class MainMenu extends Activity implements OnClickListener{

ImageButton ibEasy, ibIntermediate, ibHard, ibMusic, ibGo, ibTest, ibPractice, ibStatistic;
CheckBox cPlus, cMinus, cMulti, cDiv;

private int difficulty = 0;
private int operation = 0;
private int top = 0;
private boolean p = false, m = false, mu = false, d = false;
private boolean ispressed = false;
String name;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.mainmenu);
    Initialize();
}


private void Initialize() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    ibEasy = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButton1);
    ibIntermediate = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButton2);
    ibHard = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButton3);
    ibMusic = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButton4);
    ibGo = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButton5);
    ibPractice = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButton6);
    ibTest = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButton7);
    ibStatistic = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButton8);
    //ibEasy.setPressed(true);

    cPlus = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkBox1);
    cMinus = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkBox2);
    cMulti = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkBox3);
    cDiv = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkBox4);

    name = getIntent().getExtras().getString("Reference");

    ibEasy.setOnClickListener(this);
    ibIntermediate.setOnClickListener(this);
    ibHard.setOnClickListener(this);
    ibMusic.setOnClickListener(this);
    ibGo.setOnClickListener(this);
    ibTest.setOnClickListener(this);
    ibPractice.setOnClickListener(this);
    ibStatistic.setOnClickListener(this);
    cPlus.setOnClickListener(this);
    cMinus.setOnClickListener(this);
    cMulti.setOnClickListener(this);
    cDiv.setOnClickListener(this);


}



 if (R.id.imageButton5 == v.getId() && top == 2 && difficulty > 0 && operation > 0 )
    {
        int[] ops = new int [operation];
        ops = getoperation(ops);        
        Log.d("OPS", String.valueOf(ops.length));
        Intent i = new Intent();
        i.setClass(MainMenu.this, Test.class);
        i.putExtra("Reference2", name);
        i.putExtra("Difficulty", difficulty);
        i.putExtra("OPstring", ops);
        startActivity(i);
    } 
 private int[] getoperation(int[] ops) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    int index = 0;
    if (p == true)
    {
        ops[index] = 1;
        index++;
    }
    if (m == true)
    {
        ops[index] = 2;
        index++;
    }
    if(mu == true)
    {
        ops[index] = 3;
        index++;
    }
    if (d == true)
    {
        ops[index] = 4;
        index++;
    }
    return ops;
}


@Override
protected void onPause() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onPause();
    stopService(new Intent(MainMenu.this,SongService.class));
    finish();
}
```

my application manifest:

```
 ?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.mathmemes"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.mathmemes.Logo"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="landscape" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.mathmemes.StartPoint"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="landscape" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.StartPoint" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.mathmemes.MainMenu"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="landscape" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MENU" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.mathmemes.Test"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="landscape" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.TEST" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.mathmemes.Practice"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="landscape" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.PRACTICE" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.mathmemes.Statistic"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="landscape" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.STATISTIC" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <service android:enabled="true" android:name=".SongService"/>
</application>
```

here is my error exception on LOGCAT:

```
06-01 10:40:43.757: W/InputManagerService(58): 
Got RemoteException sending  setActive(false) notification to pid 311 uid 10036
06-01 10:40:44.758: W/NotificationService(58): 
Object died trying to hide notification
android.app.ITransientNotification$Stub$Proxy@45f43aa0 in package com.mathmemes
06-01 10:40:44.758: W/ActivityManager(58): 
 setProcessForeground called on unknown pid: 311
 06-01 10:40:44.758: W/NotificationService(58): 
 Object died trying to show notification
 android.app.ITransientNotification$Stub$Proxy@45f4d090 in package com.mathmemes
 06-01 10:40:44.758: W/ActivityManager(58): 
 setProcessForeground called on unknown pid: 311
 06-01 10:40:44.758: W/NotificationService(58): 
 Object died trying to show notification 
 android.app.ITransientNotification$Stub$Proxy@45f344d8 in package com.mathmemes
 06-01 10:40:44.767: W/ActivityManager(58):
 setProcessForeground called on unknown pid: 311
 06-01 10:40:44.767: W/NotificationService(58): 
 Object died trying to show notification 
 android.app.ITransientNotification$Stub$Proxy@45f317f0 in package com.mathmemes
 06-01 10:40:44.767: W/ActivityManager(58): 
 setProcessForeground called on unknown pid: 311
 06-01 10:44:28.064: D/SntpClient(58): 
 request time failed: java.net.SocketException: 
 Address family not supported by protocol
 06-01 10:49:28.074: D/SntpClient(58): 
 request time failed: java.net.SocketException: 
 Address family not supported by protocol
 06-01 10:54:28.090: D/SntpClient(58): 
 request time failed: java.net.SocketException: 
  Address family not supported by  protocol
 06-01 10:59:28.130: D/SntpClient(58): 
 request time failed: java.net.SocketException: 
  Address family not supported by  protocol
 06-01 11:04:28.141: D/SntpClient(58): 
 request time failed: java.net.SocketException: 
  Address family not supported by protocol



06-01 10:26:28.517: E/AndroidRuntime(271): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-01 10:26:28.517: E/AndroidRuntime(271): java.lang.RuntimeException: 
Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.mathmemes/com.mathmemes.MainMenu}:
java.lang.NullPointerException
06-01 10:26:28.517: E/AndroidRuntime(271):  
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2663)
06-01 10:26:28.517: E/AndroidRuntime(271):  
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)
06-01 10:26:28.517: E/AndroidRuntime(271):  
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125)
06-01 10:26:28.517: E/AndroidRuntime(271):  
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)
06-01 10:26:28.517: E/AndroidRuntime(271):  
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
06-01 10:26:28.517: E/AndroidRuntime(271):  
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
06-01 10:26:28.517: E/AndroidRuntime(271):  
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
06-01 10:26:28.517: E/AndroidRuntime(271):  
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-01 10:26:28.517: E/AndroidRuntime(271):  
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
06-01 10:26:28.517: E/AndroidRuntime(271):  
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
06-01 10:26:28.517: E/AndroidRuntime(271):  
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
06-01 10:26:28.517: E/AndroidRuntime(271):  
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
06-01 10:26:28.517: E/AndroidRuntime(271): 
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
06-01 10:26:28.517: E/AndroidRuntime(271):  
at com.mathmemes.MainMenu.Initialize(MainMenu.java:55)
06-01 10:26:28.517: E/AndroidRuntime(271):  
at com.mathmemes.MainMenu.onCreate(MainMenu.java:34)
06-01 10:26:28.517: E/AndroidRuntime(271): 
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
06-01 10:26:28.517: E/AndroidRuntime(271):  
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2627)
06-01 10:26:28.517: E/AndroidRuntime(271):  
... 11 more
```

i really dont know why it is not working i tried a similar code in another project and it worked so i dont know where i went wrong.

Thank you for your consideration and time. sorry for my bad English.

Comment: Whats in your LogCat? It gives you the exact line where the NullPointerException happens

Comment: i added my logcat please check it

Comment: add more logcat, the entire exception stack

Comment: what is in oncreate of MainActivity. ALso put a more detail logcat data

Comment: In the `Initialize()` method you set `OnClickListeners` for those buttons but you don't initialize them before in the `onCreate()` method like `bMcq1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.the_id_of_the_bMcq1_button);`

Comment: i did intialize them but i didnt put the whole code. anyway here is the full code of Test activity.

Comment: The exception comes from line 55 in the Initialize method. See what you got there and also check if you have the extra that you look for.

Comment: thanks man, you were right! the problem was im passing a string from startpoint activity to MainMenu so whenever im in test activity getting back to MainMenu im not passing anything so getIntent() is empty!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
>   06-01 10:26:28.517: E/AndroidRuntime(271):
>   at com.mathmemes.MainMenu.Initialize(MainMenu.java:55)

These lines say where the NPE is thrown. Can you also post the context code of MainMenu.java?

And members in class Test seem not be initialized properly, so NPE should be thrown when executing Test.Initialize(). Have you post the complete code of Test.java?

---

```
name = getIntent().getExtras().getString("Reference");
```

Here's where the NPE comes. getIntent() returns the intent use to start the Activity. If you want to handle results passing back from other Activity, you should override onActivityResult() in MainMenu:

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
}
```

*data* contains the results from other Activity. It can be set by calling setResult() before invoking finish();